# Disable Caching on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, caching, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have been using GCS to storage my images and also use the NodeJS package to upload these images to my bucket. I have noticed that if I frequently change an image, it either does one of the following:

- It changes
- It serves an old image
- It doesn't change

This seems to happen pretty randomly despite setting all of the options properly and even cross-referencing that with GCS.

I upload my images like this:

```
const options = {
    destination,
    public: true,
    resumable: false,
    metadata: {
      cacheControl: 'no-cache, max-age=0',
    },
  };

  const file = await this.bucket.upload(tempImageLocation, options);
  const { bucket, name, generation } = file[0].metadata;

  const imageUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket}/${name}`;
```

I have debated whether to use the base URL you see there or use this one: https://storage.cloud.google.com.

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong and how to always serve a fresh image. I have also tried ?ignoreCache=1 and other query parameters.

Comment: Hi @JoshuaDaiter if you think my answer helped you, please, consider upvoting/accepting it. :)

Answer (score 1):

u can try change ?ignoreCache=1 to ?ignoreCache=0.

Comment: This does actually work in my testing, similar to a trick you can use to force download of a javascript file avoiding the browser cache, append a `?random=xxx` parameter to the cloudstorage url e.g.  --`http://storage.googleapis.com/bucket_name/documentname.docx?random=xxx`

Comment: update: this only works in browser, doesn't work in API :(

Answer (score 0):

As per the official API documentation - accessible [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload) - shows, you should not need the `await`. This might be affecting your upload sometime. If you want to use the `await`, you need to have your function to be `async` in the declaration, as showed in the second example from the documentation. Your code should look like this.

```
  const bucketName = 'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket';
  const filename = 'Local file to upload, e.g. ./local/path/to/file.txt';

  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
  const storage = new Storage();

  async function uploadFile() {
    // Uploads a local file to the bucket
    await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
      // Support for HTTP requests made with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
      gzip: true,
      // By setting the option `destination`, you can change the name of the
      // object you are uploading to a bucket.
      metadata: {
        // Enable long-lived HTTP caching headers
        // Use only if the contents of the file will never change
        // (If the contents will change, use cacheControl: 'no-cache')
        cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
      },
    });

    console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
  }

  uploadFile().catch(console.error);
```

**While this is untested**, it should help you avoiding the issue with not uploading always the images.

Besides that, as explained in the official documentation of [Editing Metada](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#edit), you can change the way that metadata - which includes the cache control - is used and managed by your project. This way, you can change your cache configuration as well.

I also, would like to include the below link for a complete tutorial on how to send images to Cloud Storage with Node.js, in case you want to check a different approach.

- [Image Upload With Google Cloud Storage and Node.js](https://medium.com/@olamilekan001/image-upload-with-google-cloud-storage-and-node-js-a1cf9baa1876)

Let me know if the information helped you!